# Register access(reading/writing) in C

Tags: c, assembly, binary, cpu-registers

I have some misunderstanding of the processor register concepts. There is a register with address, let's say, 0x0345678. This register is 32 bits wide/long(doesn't matter right now, which word is the right one). As written in manual there is some kind of table/array:

```
Position   Value
 0          111111...10b
 1          111111...11b
 2          7A
 .......................
 7          3F7C
```

I have to access the value with position 2.
The first thing what I've done was:

```
#define REG 0x0345678

void somereadfunction()
{
   volatile unsigned int *pval = (volatile unsigned int *)REG;
   printf("%x", *(pval | 0x02));
}
```

And as you already guessed, it was the wrong assumption.

Another endeavor was this one:

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d, res: 0x%08X", i, *((volatile unsigned int *)REG));
    }
```

And it works. So, my question is, why and how? Does processor just switch the register value with some magic algorithm inside, written by another developer? I'm a bit confused about that. I know how to access the third bit of the register using some simple bit-wise operations, but I don't understand, how, just by calling three times the register, we will get the right value?

Thank you beforehand for your answers.

ADDED: Processor is ARM 7. Used the i2c device.

Comment: It's impossible to tell exactly what your processor (or some chip on your board) is doing without knowing what that chip is. Other than that, yes, "stuff" can store state (including how many times their ports have been read) and return different things at different times.

Comment: @Mat, processor is ARM 7

Comment: So? Such things can happen on anything (ARM, x86, PPC, whatever). What exact component are you accessing? What does the doc where you found that register address say?

Comment: @Mat, I can tell you only that it access i2c device. In docs only written that it's a kind of table, with default value h1111

Comment: The first one should give you compiler error -- `pval` is a pointer, which can't be an operand to `|`.

Comment: Well as I said, the I2C device can keep state and return different elements depending on how many times you read it. The first two values   are (probably) markers so that you can determine when the device is starting a new "cycle". Please read the docs carefully for that device.

Comment: @Mat, by your first comment you really clarified situation. And, yes, the first two are markers. I only assumed that it can be done in this way. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris, not exactly so, for some reasons, the compiler doesn't show any error messages. Only, when I started to trace it, I got a fault memory error message.

Comment: @Mat, @user1415536: This isn't a _register_ but rather a memory-mapped _FIFO_ / _LIFO_ _port_. Reading from it is kind-of equivalent to performing a `pop` operation on some device-internal hidden stack/ringbuffer - next time you call it, you'd `pop` something else. Not that unusual, but should be documented in the manual for the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why*?

Because the people who built your hardware device (that is connected to your ARM processor) probably declared just a few addresses that "belong" to the device. Then, they noticed there was more data in the hardware than registers, and it was too late to change the manual, so they decided to have some registers hold multiple values.

*How*?

The hardware has an internal counter that counts read commands from the processor. Each time the processor wants to read from the register, hardware sends it another piece of data, indexed by the invisible internal counter, and increases the counter. The counter is 3-bit, so it counts 0, 1, ..., 7, 0, 1, ... etc.

So if you want to read the data with index 2, you also have to read all other data elements (3, 4, 5, 6, and 7) to reset the invisible counter.

Answer (score 3):

Memory mapped I/O registers change their contents based on reads and writes to them. They way you described it is a bit strange though, usually one writes a value to a control register to tell the device which internal register to access and then read the value from another location.

Comment: but it works in this way. Yes, usually you have to write something, and only after that you can read the value.

Comment: sorry. I can't do it. This manual only on paper. But as Mat told, the i2c devices can do such "stuff".

Answer (score 2):

`*(pval | 0x02)` should be really be `*(pval + 0x2)` if you are trying to index into the second position in that array.

You can also set REG to the correct address by doing `REG + 0x8` before the cast to get the third 32 bit value at position 2.

This is true if this architecture uses byte-addressing, meaning every address points to a byte of data. So you can read a byte of data from 0x345678, 0x345678+1, 0x345678+2 etc. Now if you are on a 32 bit architecture, you are only concerned with 4 bytes each time. So 0x345678 is position 0, 0x345682 is position 1 and so on.

You also have to take into account memory alignment since you can't make an unaligned access. It is usually aligned at 4 byte boundaries in a 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Given 32-bit integers, `pval + 0x10` will increment an unsigned int pointer by 64 bytes `(16 * sizeof(unsigned int))`. To get the second position he should use `pval + 0x02`.